# Pass parameter to jQuery function for dynamic targets

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Below are snippets which shows the (simplified) final product I'm aiming for (you can see if you run the code).

The problem is that this isn't scalable.  My actual table is generated through a PHP loop and is hundreds of rows long.  I need some way of telling jQuery "if I click the edit button in row 60, then perform the following changes to the 60th name, age, etc.. entries.  My actual page is written in PHP, and I can tell the loop to generate Edit buttons with targets that equate to the loop iteration (id=$i), but I don't know how to make my jQuery code flexible.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#1").click(function() {
        $("#name1").html("<input type='text' name='newname1' value='' size='2' />");
        $("#age1").html("<input type='text' name='newage1' value='' size='2' />");
        $("#button1").html("<input type='button' name='newbutton1' value='submit' />");
    });
    
    $("#2").click(function() {
        $("#name2").html("<input type='text' name='newname2' value='' size='2' />");
        $("#age2").html("<input type='text' name='newage2' value='' size='2' />");
        $("#button2").html("<input type='button' name='newbutton2' value='submit' />");
    });
    
    $("#3").click(function() {
        $("#name3").html("<input type='text' name='newname3' value='' size='2' />");
        $("#age3").html("<input type='text' name='newage3' value='' size='2' />");
        $("#button3").html("<input type='button' name='newbutton3' value='submit' />");
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id='name1'>Pete</td>
        <td id='age1'>32</td>
        <td id='button1'><input id='1' type='button' value='edit' /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id='name2'>Brian</td>
        <td id='age2'>25</td>
        <td id='button2'><input id='2' type='button' value='edit' /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id='name3'>John</td>
        <td id='age3'>30</td>
        <td id='button3'><input id='3' type='button' value='edit' /></td>
    </tr>
            
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic selectors and combine the edit button click functionality like below:

```
$("input[value='edit']").click(function() {
var id=$(this).attr('id');

 $("#name"+id).html("<input type='text' name='newname' value='' size='2' />");
 $("#age"+id).html("<input type='text' name='newage' value='' size='2' />");
 $("#button"+id).html("<input type='button' name='newbutton' value='submit' />");

});
```

Comment: Hi, I can't quite get your code to run.  Can you explain what's happening in the initial selector.... $("#input[value='edit']")....?

Comment: This function is common for all buttons with value edit. So whenever the edit button is clicked this will be called. 'id' var will contain 1,2,3 based on which edit button was clicked, then the things will be modified based on that id

Comment: Is it possible there is a syntax mistake in that section?  If I replace it with $("#1") then your code works (but only for the first row of course).  Sorry I am quite new with javascript

Comment: @Tortooga There was a minor typo, edited my answer. check now

Comment: Oh I think I found it, the #input needs to be :input